# Templated Function that works for iterators over raw pointers as well as iterators over unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator, unique-ptr

Let's say I have a template function that takes a const range (or better, begin- and end-iterators) of some kind of pointer-collections. 
This function internally constructs a STL-container with pointers to reorganize the elements.

Now I want to reuse this function for unique_ptr-collections as well. I somehow need to modify the template parameters or introduce a new wrapper or overload... but how?
Is there any C++11 template magic, STL helper or boost helper?
Following an example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

// Element Class
class Foo { };

// Take a range of elements, sort them internally by their addresses and print them in order    
template <typename FooIterator>
void print_sorted_addresses(FooIterator beginFoos, FooIterator endFoos)
{
    // Sort them
    std::vector<const Foo*> elements(beginFoos, endFoos);
    std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    // Print them
    for(const auto& e : elements)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo*> raw_foos;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> unique_foos;

    // Fill them
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
        raw_foos.push_back(foo.get());
        unique_foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
    }

    print_sorted_addresses(raw_foos.cbegin(), raw_foos.cend());
    //print_sorted_Foos(unique_foos.cbegin(), unique_foos.cend()); // ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

---

The culprit seems to be the non-uniform behavior of raw pointers and smart pointers (`unique_ptr` in particular) for converting them both to raw pointers.
This can either be circumvented via a dereferencing-cycle à la `std::addressof(*p)`, but this only has well-defined behavior if p is not `nullptr`.
To reduce any runtime-checks I played with conditional templates and came up with the following:

```
template<typename Ptr> using RawPtr = typename std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::element_type*; 

// raw pointers like int**, const char*, ...
template<typename Ptr>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<Ptr>::value, RawPtr<Ptr>>::type make_raw(Ptr ptr) { return ptr; }

// smart pointers like unique_ptr, shared_ptr, ... 
template<typename Ptr>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<Ptr>::value, RawPtr<Ptr>>::type make_raw(Ptr& ptr) { return ptr.get(); }
```

This could be used in @tclamb's iterator, or in boost::transform_iterator as in @Praetorian's answer. But it still feels strange to build upon the specific get()-member of a smart-pointer implementation instead of the operator*-interface what makes a pointer a pointer.

Comment: Don't you want to print `e` and not `&e`?

Comment: I wanted to use a custom object, but don't wanted to implement operator<< for cout and operator< for sorting... That's why I did everything on the address. (Of course this is only for the example)

Comment: Aahh, you're absolutely right... Inside the range-based for I already have the Pointers... I'll edit. Thx!

Comment: You could also use `vector<FooIterator>` instead and then use care that sorting takes place with respect to the contained value instead of to `FooIterator` itself.

Comment: @pmr. Should work, but this would imply modifying the inner logic of the function. (And would trigger additional template instantiations for the internally used containers for each new Iterator type...)

Comment: The additional template instantiation seems like a bit contrived criterion to me and modifying the modification seems straight-forward, but it can't be helped if those are your requirements.

Comment: @pmr. The change could be straightforward but would still surprise any reviewer who would ask why I am not using normal pointers. Ideally, I don't want my 'interface-problem' affect the inner logic at all. (And: Compilation time is precious ;))

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic approach that wraps the pointer iterator. On dereference, it dereferences the stored iterator (yielding the (smart-)pointer), and dereferences again (yielding a reference to the *pointee*), and then returns the pointee's address (via `std::addressof()`). The rest of the implementation is just iterator boilerplate.

```
template<typename Iterator,
         typename Address = decltype(std::addressof(**std::declval<Iterator>()))
         >
class address_iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, Address>
{
public:
    address_iterator(Iterator i) : i_{std::move(i)} {};

    Address operator*() const {
        auto&& ptr = *i_;
        return i_ == nullptr ? nullptr : std::addressof(*ptr);
    };

    Address operator->() const {
        return operator*();
    }

    address_iterator& operator++() {
        ++i_;
        return *this;
    };

    address_iterator operator++(int) {
        auto old = *this;
        operator++();
        return old;
    }

    bool operator==(address_iterator const& other) const {
        return i_ == other.i_;
    }

private:
    Iterator i_;
};

template<typename I, typename A>
bool operator!=(address_iterator<I, A> const& lhs, address_iterator<I, A> const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

template<typename Iterator>
address_iterator<Iterator> make_address_iterator(Iterator i) {
    return i;
}
```

Live example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77802fc21ce4f9f7) (with a `std::random_shuffle()` thrown in for fun). :)

Comment: `auto&& old = *this;` does NOT make a copy. You want `auto old = *this;` in `operator++(int)`. Also, `operator->` should technically be `const`.

Comment: Isn't `addressof(*p)` undefined behavior for `p==nullptr`?

Comment: @ThomasB. Probably. I added a quick little check to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code when dealing with `unique_ptr` is this line:

```
std::vector<const Foo*> elements(beginFoos, endFoos);
```

The `vector` constructor is going to try and copy the `unique_ptr`s, which is not allowed; and you're interested in what the `unique_ptr` points to anyway. So you need an extra level of dereferencing to yield a reference to the managed object. This can be achieved using [Boost.IndirectIterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html).

Using `boost::indirect_iterator` will yield `Foo const&`, which can then be converted to `Foo const *` by wrapping it in [Boost.TransformIterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html), and passing [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) as the unary predicate to `boost::transform_iterator`.

```
template <typename FooIterator>
void print_sorted_addresses(FooIterator beginFoos, FooIterator endFoos) {
    std::vector<Foo const *> elements(
      boost::make_transform_iterator(boost::make_indirect_iterator(beginFoos), 
                                     std::addressof<Foo>),
      boost::make_transform_iterator(boost::make_indirect_iterator(endFoos),
                                     std::addressof<Foo>));

    std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    for(const auto& e : elements)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed29703269592f9f)

Comment: Nice use of boost. But won't the `indirect_iterator` produce undefined behavior for `nullptr`s?

Comment: @ThomasB. Yes, it will

Answer (score 0):

My 2 coins

```
Foo* get(Foo* const& p) {
    return p;
}

Foo* get(std::unique_ptr<Foo> const& up) {
    return up.get();
}


// Take a range of elements, sort them internally by their addresses and print
// them in order    
template <typename ConstIt>
void print_sorted_addresses(const ConstIt& cbegin, const ConstIt& cend) {

    using deref_type = decltype(*cbegin);
    using raw_ptr_type = decltype(get(*cbegin));

    std::vector<raw_ptr_type> v;
    v.reserve(cend - cbegin);

    std::transform(cbegin, cend, 
                   std::back_inserter(v),
                   [] (const deref_type& p) {
                        return get(p);
                   });


    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(const auto& p : v)
        std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```